# C# parse headers with sections of the parameters

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, http-headers, mime

How we can parse Headers with sections of the parameters (see rfc2231(https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2231)). For example:

```
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;
 name*0*=US-ASCII''%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0;
 name*1*=%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BD%D0;
 name*2*=%B0%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83%20#Z_226.xlsx
```

If we parse with:

```
var ct = new ContentType(headerValueText);
var name = ct.Name;
```

It returns null. Name will be in Parameters collection with keys ["name*0*", "name*1*", "name*2*"].

How we can parse name and decode it?

For now i use following approach:

```
var namesColection = new List<(int position, string value)>();
foreach (DictionaryEntry parametr in ct.Parameters)
{
    if (parametr.Key.ToString().Contains("name"))
    {
        var position = parametr.Key.ToString().Split('*')[1];
        namesColection.Add((int.Parse(position), parametr.Value.ToString()));
    }
}
var nameString = string.Join("", namesColection.OrderBy(p => p.position));
var decodingName = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(nameString.ToString().Split('\'')[2], Encoding.UTF8);
```

Comment: What is `headerValueText`? What does your existing code return, and what do you want it to return?

Comment: headerValueText is a value of header Content-Type (application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;name*0*=US-ASCII''%D0%...). I want get a content-type header with name parametr (already decoded with correct value that storing in ct.Name property). But ContentType class can't read name property. How can we do this? Thanks!

Comment: Existing code combine all section of name parametr and decode it byt utf8, then we can store decodingName  in ct.Name.

Comment: If you're using `ContentType` class from `System.Net.Mime` it won't work. You have to create custom class and parser.

Comment: What is wrong with your current code? This is a custom format, I think you would have to do this manually.